Automated Process User has an upcoming task
I have a trigger on a sales engagement runtime object, when a CDC is detected, the trigger publishes a PE, then a PE triggered-flow runs, which later creates a Task, this new task record is getting the AssignedTo field/assigned to Automated Process User instead of the user who caused the PE to be published ( that's what I want to happen), despite that I pass the initiating user Id from the PE to the flow to the new task record, but it still shows the task owner as APU (Automated Process has an upcoming task)!
I'm trying to update the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig somehow to solve it but I'm new to this metadata roadblocks.
anyone had this issue? any suggestions are appreciated!

Hi, thanks for your question. When creating the Task, are you explicitly setting the owner value, or leaving it blank?

I'm explicitly passing the RunningUser's Id (me or a Rep) and assigning it to task
Task OwnerId = varRunningUserId
but I figured that PEs flow run in the context of Automated process user and IDK how to switch that to a real user

You need to assign the OwnerId field explicitly on the Task record being created. You might want to achieve this by having a dedicated text field for the owner id to be filled in in your Platform Event (for the "when the CDC is detected, the trigger publishes an event" part). That way, whenever your flow runs because of that event, it will assign the OwnerId value based on the value you passed on your Platform Event at the beginning.
To summarize:

Create a text field (18 chars) on the Platform Event.
Assign it the value of the user who made the change (obtain this info from the Change Data Capture event).
In your flow, assign that value from the PE to the OwnerId field on the Task.


I did that by the first try! it doesn't work! I wish :) why ? the text field on the Platform event that's supposed to carry the UserId to the subscribed flow gets automatically assigned the Id of the APU (Per debug logs), why? its a limitation related to the context in which platform event run on salesforce as they get executed asynchronously.
I did something related to PlatformEventSubscriberConfig to switch the user from APU to a regular user, which I managed to do for my User, but I want it to dynamically capture and assign the created Task to the User who caused the logic to run

How so? The commitUser on the CDC header contains the ID of the user who did the change operation, not the Automated Process user. Did you use that as reference for your Platform Event field data?

Update:
I just retrieved commitUser Id in the trigger and PE, stored it in a flow Var and I was able to assign the the created task and other records to the user that triggered the logic to run, not to the APU! THANKS a lot Renato!

No problem! :) Glad it worked out!
